# Linq query to create 3 objects from one table. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, linq

Let say we have a table like this:

```
id  client  order_number    item_ref    size    quantity
1   CL-0001 123456          ITEM-0001   small   20
2   CL-0001 123456          ITEM-0001   big     20
3   CL-0001 123456          ITEM-0002   small   20
4   CL-0001 123456          ITEM-0002   big     20
5   CL-0001 456789          ITEM-0001   small   10
6   CL-0001 456789          ITEM-0001   medium  10
7   CL-0001 456789          ITEM-0001   big     10
8   CL-0001 456789          ITEM-0002   small   10
9   CL-0001 456789          ITEM-0002   medium  10
10  CL-0001 456789          ITEM-0002   big     10
```

I would like to get all rows but this unique table is actually 3 objects in my code.

An object client that contains orders that contains items.

So in my code I have this:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible with group by to create my model with one LinQ query?

I ask this question because I need to print invoices and depending on the type of item sometime I need to group all size and sum the quantities and sometime I need to display the detail of each quantity.

Comment: i think you're classes is not complete.

Comment: @Dr. Stitch What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = source.GroupBy(x => x.client)
                .Select(x => new Client
                        {
                            Reference  = x.Key,
                            Orders = x.GroupBy(y => y.order_number)
                                        .Select(y => new Order
                                            {
                                                Reference  = y.Key,
                                                Items = y.Select(z => new Item
                                                                {
                                                                    Reference  = z.item_ref,
                                                                    Size = z.Size,
                                                                    Quantity = z.Quantity
                                                                }).ToList()
                                            }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: The GroupBy followed by Select is not working. Are you sure of your query?

Comment: Not working means? VS throws any error while compile time or error in runtime?